# How Can I Pass Two parameters to perform AND in crystal reports VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have created a Report using Crystal Reports. I need to view this report using report viewer. I need to pass two parameters. But my code shown below does not work.
All help is appreciated.

I have created the paramters and applied them using select Expert and they work.

```
{viewNamazTime.ttDateYear} = {?SelectYear} and {viewNamazTime.ttDateMonth} = {?SelectMonth}
```

However I am finding it difficult to pass parameters through code.

```
            Dim rptViewer As New rptNamazTime

        '' Set Database Logon Details 
        rptViewer.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "*****", "MAIN-PC", "xxxxx")

        ' display header
        Dim sHeader As Object
        sHeader = rptViewer.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("txtHeading")
        sHeader.Text = StrConv(m_sMonth, vbUpperCase) & "  " & m_theYear & "  SALAAH TIMETABLE"

        ''Pass filter Paramter
        rptViewer.SetParameterValue("SelectYear", m_theYear)
        rptViewer.SetParameterValue("SelectMonth", m_theMonth)
        crvNamazTime.ReportSource = rptViewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report also takes an array as parameter. You can put your parameters into an array and pass it to your report.